# Problems with Git::Repository concerning Umlaut in use with Mojolicious or HTML::Entities

Tags: perl, mojolicious

I have a problem while displaying log-entries from git in a website regarding the Umlauts. I don't have an idea where to look for solutions, so I ask for help here. I do think that it might be an issue with encoding, but `use utf8` did not have any effect in my tries. I made some effort to explain the problem in the hope to find a helpful answer. Thanks a lot.

So I create a repo with umlauts in the commit message:

```
echo "Hello Wörld!" > a_file.txt
git init
git add a_file.txt
git commit -m "Some Ümlaut: üöä"
```

I can now look at it in cmd, no problems occur:

```
$ git log
  ...
    Some Ümlaut: üöä
```

I can also print this stuff in Perl without issues.
I'll call:

```
use Git::Repository;
my $repo = Git::Repository->new(work_tree => ".");
my $log  = $repo->run( "log" );
print "$log\n";
```

which gives me the same output as the shell example above.

The problem occurs when I'm using `Mojolicious`.
Here is an example:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/' => sub {
  my $self = shift;

  use Git::Repository;
  my $repo = Git::Repository->new(work_tree => ".");
  my $log  = $repo->run( "log" );
  $self->render(text => "$log  -- möre Ümläut\n" );
};

app->start;
```

When I run this, the Umlaut in the string will work, but not those coming from the commit message. To show it I can run the above Perl as following:

```
perl mojo.pl daemon
```

I then call the website with curl:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:3000
...
    Some Ãmlaut: Ã¼Ã¶Ã¤  -- möre Ümläut
```

As I said: Umlauts from Git fail, rest is ok.

So I thought I was clever and translate them to HTML entities:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Git::Repository;
use HTML::Entities 'encode_entities';

my $repo = Git::Repository->new(work_tree => ".");
my $log = $repo->run( "log" );
print "$log\n";

my $htmlified = encode_entities($log);
print "$htmlified\n";
```

But calling this, only the first output is good. `HTML::Entities` has the same problem as `Mojolicious`:

```
...
Some Ümlaut: üöä
...
Some &Atilde;&#156;mlaut: &Atilde;&frac14;&Atilde;&para;&Atilde;&curren;
```

Is it, that the problem is in `Git::Repository`, or where do I fail?
I used Perl 5.16 on Ubuntu 12.04 for this tests.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out how to do it, `decode_utf8()` is your friend here.
But I am still not sure why this step is needed...

Here is how it goes:

```
use Mojolicious::Lite;

# we need this lib, part of core
use Encode;

get '/' => sub {
  my $self = shift;

  use Git::Repository;
  my $repo = Git::Repository->new(work_tree => ".");
  my $log  = $repo->run( "log" );

  # this call does the trick
  my $wtf  = decode_utf8($log);

  $self->render(text => "$wtf  -- möre Ümläut\n" );
};

app->start;
```

Hope this helps other people as well. If someone thinks there should be a bugreport to one of those libs mentioned please tell here. I have no clue, if this is a workaround, bug or feature :-P

Comment: This also works with the example using HTML::Entities, posted above. Print to stdout does now no more work (`Some �mlaut: ��`), but the HTML-entities work fine: `Some &Uuml;mlaut: &uuml;&ouml;&auml;`

Comment: The reason is that most likely that Mojolicious is careful to encode before rendering; it is therefore important that you decode inputs that come from external sources. A key tenant of unicode is that you decode and encode at the boundaries of your program.

Comment: Afaik now: the problem is, that Git::Repository does not return Perl-Chars, but Bytes "as-is".

Comment: Correct, and thus you must decode them. Unicode is hard, lets go shopping :-)